# Degree of nodes and Degree centrality

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, eigenvector, adjacency-matrix

I got an idea about **degree centrality** and it's disadvantage from the attached image here and web but why isn't the **degree of nodes** always give a faithful indication of the centrality of nodes in a network? Any example would be much helpful. Cheers!!

[image]

Comment: How could degree of a node give measure about the centrality of the node? Assume one at a corner with many adjacent nodes; other at the center with limited nodes connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a "double star graph," like this one here:

```
      *  *         *  *
       \ |         | /
     * - *  - *  - * - *
       / |         | \
      *  *         *  *
```

While both of the nodes at the centers of the stars have a high degree and reasonable centrality, the node that probably is the "most" central is the one linking the two stars, since a huge fraction of the paths between the nodes go through that central node. We could make each of the star centers have arbitrarily large degree, but in the end the most central node will be the one in the center, which has degree two. In that sense, the degree of a node can be an arbitrarily bad predictor of whether it's the most central node in the graph, for some "reasonable" definition of central.